# Background Image works offline but online on website it doesn't appear (CSS)

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've made a site, checked it offline and it worked fine but then I upload the files for it to my website and for somereason on the website, the background image does not appear at all but the css and everything else works so I thought my path was wrong but I didn't change anything for the path and it still worked offline but not online on the website, what's wrong?

for over an hour I've kept trying every possible path that could work and I haven't had any luck, I've even changed the image to see if that works and nope no result but everything worked offline, same name and folder names EXACTLY but I have no clue whats wrong.

rather than type and make it confusing, these are files:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4I7T.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1ZLf.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7LkH.jpg

here's the code:

```
body {
  background-image: url("pics/back.jpg");
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your folder name is Pics (capital P). In some cases case sensitivity may cause problems in CSS so try it

Comment: tried it, no luck and also i dont know if this means anything but if you know anything about this let me know so i can go to the pics folder thru my website (https://imgur.com/a/s7c0f06) and when i click the image called back.jpg (background image) thru there it says error 404

Comment: The file extension may be blocked by the .htaccess file. Try adding this line to the file:

AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG

Comment: to what file? sorry im a little slow lol

Comment: it seems like comments are getting deleted but hope you see this, i used background-image: url("./pics/back.png"); instead of background-image: url("./pics/back.jpg"); because i changed it to png cuz png wasnt getting error 404 when i went to click it n directory lists but still no luck, no background image

Comment: I can see you have the back.jpg file at the root level also - have you tried accessing that file via **background-image: url("back.jpg");** to ensure it's not an issue with the pics/Pics folder.